# Вот мне не нравится сильно этот пункт Розенталя, т. к., читая его, можно сказать, что якоб во всех предложениях, снизу написанных, запятушка не нужна

Tags: запятые

Вот мне не нравится сильно этот пункт Розенталя, т. к., читая его, можно сказать, что якоб во всех предложениях, снизу написанных, запятушка не нужна: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=112. (А говорю о 1-м пункте в примечании.)

> Вычислите эти уравнения(,) не используя калкулятор.

> Она домой вернулась(,) являясь мокрой.

> А вы(,) по-немецки говоря-то(,) можете английскому учить-таки?

> Тебе надо говорить(,) ни на кого внимание не обращая.

> Невозможно(,) в телефон смотря(,) что-то, что говорят, понимать!

А правда какая же-с?